# updateTabsetPanel with a Rshiny modul app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I developed a shiny app with different modules and files and I have some issues with my updateTabsetPanel  :
A main file where each tab item are a different module in a different file.
I have the module explore and annotate which are call like this:

```
#### in the main app

server <- function(input,output,session){
  ns <- session$ns

 ## Sidebar panel for inputs
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
  sidebarMenu(id = "tabs_menu",
    menuItem("Input data",tabName ="datafile", icon = icon("file-import")),
    menuItem("Explore", tabName = "explore", icon = icon("microscope")),
    menuItem("Annotate", tabName = "annotate", icon = icon("edit")),
    menuItem("Clusters", tabName = "cluster", icon = icon("asterisk"))
  )})


global_data <- callModule(Module_input_data_server, "data_module" )


#Module explore
  
  observeEvent(input$tabs_menu,{
    if(input$tabs_menu=="explore"){
      callModule(Module_explore_server, "explore_module", global_data )
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = TRUE, ignoreInit = TRUE)

 #Module annotate
 observeEvent(input$tabs_menu,{
   if(input$tabs_menu=="annotate"){
     callModule(Module_annotate_server, "annotate_module",global_data)
   }
 }, ignoreNULL = TRUE, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}
```

In the explore module I have different modules, one is the table I would like to return thank to the module annotate after a click on  on a button. So the goal is to return to explore after the click on the action button. but it's doesn't work.

```
#### in the annotate module the observe event for the click button

Module_annotate_server  <- function(input, output,session, rv) {
  req(rv$data)

  ns <- session$ns
  observeEvent(input$annotateButton,{
    req(rv$data)
    print("how")
    # if(is.null(rv$secure)){
    if(!is.null(input$newCol) && input$newCol != "") {
      print("how1")
      new.column <- rep(NA,nrow(rv$data))
      rv$data <- cbind(rv$data, new.column)
      colnames(rv$data)[ncol(rv$data)] <- input$newCol
      rv$annotationCol <- input$newCol
    } else if(!is.null(input$annotationCol) && input$annotationCol != "") {
      print("how2")
      rv$annotationLabels <- unique(rv$data[,input$annotationCol])
      rv$annotationCol <- input$annotationCol
    }
    if(length(input$labelsList)>0) {
      print("how3")
      new.labels <- unlist(strsplit(input$labelsList, "\\s*,\\s*"))
      if(length(new.labels)>0) {
        rv$annotationLabels <- c(input$annotationLabels, new.labels)
      }
    }
    if(is.null(rv$annotationLabels) || length(rv$annotationLabels) == 0) {
      showNotification("Some labels must be provided.", type ="error", duration = NULL)
    } else {
      # Move to the Explore tab
       updateTabsetPanel(session , "tabs_menu", selected = "explore")
     }
}
```

I would like to know what is the problem maybe the session or other things if you have idea.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `module_annotate_server` doesn't have a return value.  That's why it doesn't return anything.  You need to create a reactive in the module containing the data you want to return, then return the name of the reactive at the end of the module's server function.  Something like this:

```
returnValue <- reactive({
.... some code here ....
})

return(returnValue)
```

Also, don't put your `callModule`s inside reactives.  That's a recipe for disaster.  Simply put them in the main body of the main server function:

```
exploreVal <- callModule(Module_explore_server, "explore_module", global_data )
```

You can then refer to the module's return value with `exploreVal()`.  Do a similar thing for your `annotate_module`.