# Viewing Reactive Objects in a Session with Their Values in a Local R Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I've built a moderately lengthy R application which has reactivity based off of data returned from a number of API calls. The data is retrieved as a list with a global assignment (`<<-`) and used by other reactive components later on.

The problem I've come across is that with multiple users on the application, the global variable is reassigned to the latest users API call mixing up the values across users. To avoid the problem, I am rewriting the code so that there are no global assignments on user data since shiny should automatically keep session data separate across users. I'm able to successfully build a small test case using `reactiveValues()` which runs on reactive data without registering any global variables.

My question is, Is it possible to check the values of a session environment like you would using global variables? How do I go about verifying data values if I can't see them like global objects in the environment pane?

I've tried using a `browser()` in the server function to switch environments but because the objects are reactive, I only get them to show up as functions instead of their actual values. I can print the value of objects separately by using a `print(*reactiveObject()*)` but I'm looking for a way to do this so that I can see all of the session variables in order to make debugging more sustainable.

Here is the example of an application that doesn't produce a global environment variable. but still runs. The app requires the `dplyr`, `tigris`, and `sf` libraries.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Reactivity Test"),
    
    # State Text Input
    textInput(inputId = "stateInput",
                      label = "State",
                      value = "IA"),
    
    # Call Tigris API Button
    actionButton(inputId = "TigrisCall",
                 label = "Call Tigris"),
    
    # Plot Table Button
    actionButton(inputId = "plotTable",
                 label = "Plot Table"),
    
    # Print Value in Console Button
    actionButton(inputId = "valueButton",
                 label = "Print Value"),
    
    
    p(),
    
    # Table UI slot
    dataTableOutput("tableOut")
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Setting Reactive Value
  Data <- reactiveValues(Tigris = NULL)
  
  # Taking State Text Box Input
  text <- reactive(input$stateInput)
  
  # Pull Data on Button Click
  observeEvent(input$TigrisCall, {
    Data$Tigris <- tigris::counties(state = input$stateInput)
  })
  
  # Update Table Reactively (testing to see that new reactive object can be created)
  tableUpdate <- reactive({
      Data$Tigris %>%
      st_drop_geometry()
  }) 
  
  # Plot Data Table
  observeEvent(input$plotTable, {
    output$tableOut <- renderDataTable({tableUpdate()})
  })
  
  # Print the Value of a Reactive Variable in Console
  observeEvent(input$valueButton, {
    print(tableUpdate())
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As to why nesting reactives is not a good idea, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76514371/shiny-stuck-in-infinite-loop-when-iterating-over-reactive-values) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66100812/r-shiny-predict-model-outputs-with-user-inputs) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535986/updatetabsetpanel-with-a-rshiny-modul-app).  In fact, I'm surprised it works here.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to wrap `output$tableOut <- renderDataTable({tableUpdate()})` in an `observeEvent`.  And you probably shouldn't...

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Limey. In the original application, I use a button to generate shape files to plot on a map. The goal was to sort of emulate that here. 

What would be the better way to generate the table output tied to a button event?

Comment: Simply place a reference to the button insude the `reactive`.  If you want `tableOut` to update *only* when the button is clicked, wrap the remainder of the code in `isolate({ ... })`.

Comment: @Limey So I guess the code would look like this then? I understand that this invalidates `tableUpdate()`, but I couldn't quite understand why this is preferred over the `observeEvent()`? Am I otherwise nesting two reactive observers, is that why?

`output$tableOut <- renderDataTable({
    input$plotTable
    isolate(tableUpdate())
    })
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option, which may or may not give you what you want.  Rather than creating `reactive` objects in the server function I save them in `session$userData`.  As described [here](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.6.0/session.html), `session$userData` is "An environment for app authors and module/package authors to store whatever session-specific data they want".  It's an environment, so we can interrogate it.

Here's prototype function to do that:

```
  examineEnvironment <- function(env = session$userData) {
    for (name in names(env)) {
      x <- env[[name]]
      if (is.reactive(x)) {
        print(name)
        print(x())
      } else if (is.function(x)) {
        print(paste0(name, ": ", "Function"))
      } else if (is.null(x)) {
        print(paste0(name, ": ", "NULL"))
      } else {
        print(paste0(name, ": ", "Something else"))
      }
    }
  }
```

You can adapt it to your own purposes.

So change how you respond to your `valueButton` click to

```
  observeEvent(input$valueButton, {
    examineEnvironment()
  })
```

and you will see the current contents of `session$userData` written to the console.  The convention you need to adopt is to write objects you want to debug to `session$userData`.  Obviously, you can modify my solution stub to print only those elements you are interested in.

**EDIT**

To answer OP's question about using `isolate`...

No.  You misuderstand.  You use `isolate` when creating the `reactive`.  For example,

```
tableUpdate <- reactive({
  input$plotTable
  isolate({
      Data$Tigris %>%
      st_drop_geometry()
  })
})
```

leaving the `renderDataTable` call as

```
output$tableOut <- renderDataTable({tableUpdate()})
```

Incidentally, I'd rename `tableUpdate` as `updatedTable`.  `tableUpdate` looks to me like a verb, so I immediately think it's a function.  Because functions, like verbs, "do things".  `updatedTable` is a noun.  So it's a thing.  An object.  Though, as a `reactive`, I accept it's (a function under the hood and) a thing that may change over time...

Comment: Thank you for this. When assigning variables to `session$userData` do you just assign it using the normal assignment method `session$userData$updatedTable <- *value*`?