# Datatable is generated when changing input parameters even though submit button is not clicked

Tags: r, input, shiny, action-button, shinymodules

I am utilizing Shiny modules to define the user interface (UI) and server components for parameter modules as well as for a datatable module. The desired behavior is that the datatable should be generated or filtered only when the submit button is pressed.

The current behavior is as follows: When the app is initially run, it functions correctly, and the datatable is not generated until the submit button is pressed. However, if I change the input parameters a second time, the datatable is generated without requiring the submit button to be pressed.

The desired behavior is to consistently require the submit button to be pressed for the datatable to be generated, regardless of whether input parameters are changed.

here is an example which gives this behaviour

```
data <- data.frame(
  Input1 = c(1,2,3),
  Input2 = c(1,2,3),
  Input3 = c(1,2,3)
)


param_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    numericInput(ns("input1"), "Input 1", value = 0),
    numericInput(ns("input2"), "Input 2", value = 0),
    numericInput(ns("input3"), "Input 3", value = 0),
    actionButton(ns("submit"), "Submit")
  )
  
}

param_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id,function(input, output, session) {
    
    return(list(
     input1 = reactive({input$input1}),
     input2 = reactive({input$input2}),
     input3 = reactive({input$input3}),
     submit = reactive({input$submit})
    ))
  })
}
  
  datatable_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    
    tagList(
      dataTableOutput(ns("table"))
    )
    
  }
  
  datatable_server <- function(id,input1, input2,input3) {
    moduleServer(id,function(input, output, session) {
      
      data1 <- reactive({data %>% filter(Input1 == input1() & Input2 == input2() & Input3 == input3())})
      output$table <- renderDataTable(data1())
    })
  }
    
  




ui <- fluidPage(
  param_ui(id = "param"),
  datatable_ui(id = "datatb")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  param <- param_server(id = "param")
  
  observeEvent(param$submit(), {
    datatable_server(id = "datatb",
                     input1 = param$input1,
                     input2 = param$input2,
                     input3 = param$input3)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `reactive`s update whenever any `reactive` on which they depend changes.  Your data table depends on `input$input1`, input$input2`  and `input$input3`.  (But not on `input$submit`.)  To get the effect you want, add a reference to `input$submit` as the first line of the `data1` reactive and wrap the `filter`ing in a call to `isolate`.

Comment: Another way is to make data1 a `eventReactive` object depending on `input$submit.`

Comment: Hello @Limey Thanks for the response. Please can you guide me on how to isolate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Viewing Reactive Objects in a Session with Their Values in a Local R Shiny Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899778/viewing-reactive-objects-in-a-session-with-their-values-in-a-local-r-shiny-appli)

Comment: @Limey I tried this `data1 <- reactive({
   input$submit
      isolate({data %>% filter(Input1 == input1() & Input2 == input2() & Input3 == input3())})
   })` but I am getting the error: Error in path.expand: invalid 'path' argument

Answer (score 0):

One way is shown below.

```
datatable_server <- function(id,sub, input1, input2,input3) {
  moduleServer(id,function(input, output, session) {
    
    data1 <- eventReactive(sub(), {data %>% filter(Input1 == input1() & Input2 == input2() & Input3 == input3())})
    output$table <- renderDataTable(data1())
    
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  param_ui(id = "param"),
  datatable_ui(id = "datatb")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  param <- param_server(id = "param")
  
  observeEvent(param$submit(), {
    datatable_server(id = "datatb",
                     sub = param$submit,
                     input1 = param$input1,
                     input2 = param$input2,
                     input3 = param$input3)
  })
  
}
```